# The requested page cannot be found. Joomla 3 website

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

Someone please help me here. I used a favourite Joomla template for a site, the site has been working good but now When Someone tries to access it, it shows an error page. 1064 - Error:1064. Please What can I do to have the site back on error free?

Thank you.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ORDER BY content.created DESC' at line 25 SQL=

```
SELECT content.id AS id, content.access AS access, content.catid AS cid, 
       categories.name AS catname, categories.alias AS cat_alias, 
       users.email AS author_email, content.created_by_alias AS author_alias,
       content.created_by AS author_id, content_rating.rating_sum AS
       rating_sum, content_rating.rating_count AS rating_count 
FROM ii03y_k2_items AS content 
     LEFT JOIN ii03y_k2_categories AS categories ON categories.id = content.catid   
     LEFT JOIN ii03y_users AS users ON users.id = content.created_by 
     LEFT JOIN ii03y_k2_rating AS content_rating ON content_rating.itemID = content.id 
WHERE 
ORDER BY content.created DESC
```

Comment: your Query has Where Clause but no condition here, so remove Where Clause

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because your Query has `Where Clause` but no condition here, so remove `Where Clause` from query or add condition if any.